# Challenge response from CFEngine Server Failure while conencting cygwin to CFEngine

Tags: software-distribution, cfengine

```
when i run from windows-7 with cygwin to connect CFEngine bersion 3.4.2   
cf-agent -Bs 217.64.173.210

Challenge response from server 217.64.173.210/217.64.173.210 was incorrect!
I: Made in version 'not specified' of '/var/cfengine/inputs/update.cf' near line 47
!! Authentication dialogue with 217.64.173.210 failed
```

Challenge response from server 217.64.173.210/217.64.173.210 was incorrect!
    I: Made in version 'not specified' of '/var/cfengine/inputs/update.cf' near line

```
and in  /var/cfengine/inputs/update.cf on line 47 is 
47 : perms => m("600"),

on cgwin in folder keys 
/var/cfengine/ppkeys
```

localhost.pub
   localhost.priv
   root-MD5=b8825ba0a0e7017e34b15766d3b3ac58 (which is also at CFEngine Server Side shared ky)
    on Cf-Engine Server Side
     /var/cfengine/ppkeys/
       localhost.priv
    localhost.pub 
        root-MD5=b8825ba0a0e7017e34b15766d3b3ac58

With Regards
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Did you also get the server to trust the client's key? like so:

`cf-key -t root-MD5=b8825ba0a0e7017e34b15766d3b3ac58`
(on the server)

Also, try restarting cf-serverd in verbose mode with the -v switch on the server, and watch what error messages you get on that end.